# Kubelet API access from k8s operator

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I playing with operator-sdk and trying to issue an API call to Kubelet on a specific node.

My API calls result in result code 403 - Forbidden.

Below is the relevant code piece:

```golang
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(r.Config)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Info("Failed to get clientset")
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
    logger.Info("Successfully got clientset")

    restClient := clientset.CoreV1().RESTClient()

    for _, container := range pod.Spec.Containers {
        kubeletAPI := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes/%s/proxy/checkpoint/%s/%s/%s", pms.Spec.SourceNode, pms.Spec.Namespace, pms.Spec.PodName, container.Name)
        result := restClient.Post().AbsPath(kubeletAPI).Do(context.TODO())
        rawBody, _ := result.Raw()
        if result.Error() != nil {
            logger.Info("Failed to checkpoint container", "namespace", pms.Spec.Namespace, "podName", pms.Spec.PodName, "containerName", container.Name)
        } else {
            logger.Info("Succeded to checkpoint container")
        }

        logger.Info("Checkpoint result", "result", result, "response", string(rawBody))

    }
```

Below is the role.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: manager-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes/proxy
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - migration.pantarhei.ai
  resources:
  - podmigrations
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - patch
  - update
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - migration.pantarhei.ai
  resources:
  - podmigrations/finalizers
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - migration.pantarhei.ai
  resources:
  - podmigrations/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - patch
  - update
```

Below is the response:

```
2023-09-25T17:34:07Z    INFO    Checkpoint result       {"controller": "podmigration", "controllerGroup": "migration.pantarhei.ai", "controllerKind": "PodMigration", "PodMigration": {"name":"podmigration-sample","namespace":"pantarhei-operator-system"}, "namespace": "pantarhei-operator-system", "name": "podmigration-sample", "reconcileID": "237abbaf-36ac-4562-9182-b183ba8e6e70", "result": {}, "response": "{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"forbidden: User \\\"system:serviceaccount:pantarhei-operator-system:pantarhei-operator-controller-manager\\\" cannot post path \\\"/http:/localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes/pantarhei-dp1/proxy/checkpoint/pantarhei-operator-system/ubuntu/ubuntu-container\\\"\",\"reason\":\"Forbidden\",\"details\":{},\"code\":403}\n"}
```

I cannot understand what permission I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

`kubelet` agents only communicate with the k8s API server. Whatever the thing you are trying to get done with `kubelet`, should be possible with k8s API server access. In the operator-pattern, the operator pods don't do any direct communication with `kubelet`.

See [CNCF Operator White Paper](https://github.com/cncf/tag-app-delivery/blob/main/operator-wg/whitepaper/Operator-WhitePaper_v1-0.md#security) 's security section,

[image]

Comment: is there anyway to allow my operator to issue command to the kubelet?
I wont be using this approach do production...